# After import: Can not view order: The requested Payment Method is not available

Tags: import, payment

I imported some orders from another store. Some of them I can not view in backend because the payment method is not installed in the new shop.

How can I view the orders without installing the missing payment method?

Some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add the payment method which is installed on the new store and provide that method in the order import script or sheet instead of the missing payment method and do the re-import or manually add the payment method where missing directly in the database where it is missing.